# Uploaded image in ImageField is not shown by generic CreateView/DetailView/UpdateView

Tags: django, imagefield

When uploading an image, the image file is stored in the desired folder. Good! But the generic view doesn't show the stored image but only:

[image]

My code looks like this:

model:

```py
def tenant_images_path(instance, filename):
    # generate filename like:
    return 'data/1/images/2023/03/01/' + filename
    
class ArticleModel(models.Model):
    product_image = models.ImageField(_('Product image'), upload_to=tenant_images_path)
```

article_create.html template:

```html
<h1>{% trans "Create new article" %}</h1>
<div class="col-md-10">
<form action="{% url 'article-create' %}" method="post" class="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {% bootstrap_form form %}
  {% buttons %}
  <button type="submit">{% trans 'Create' %}</button>
  {% endbuttons %}
</form>
</div>
```

article_update.html template:

```html
<h1>{% trans "Update article" %}</h1>
<div class="col-md-10">
  <form action="" method="post" class="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {% bootstrap_form form %}
  {% buttons %}
  <button type="submit">{% trans "Update" %}</button>
  {% endbuttons %}
</form>
</div>
```

I expected the generic views to handle the display of the image. Am I wrong?

Comment: You can simply display the image in anchor tag, using `instance.product_image.url`.

Answer (score 0):

No, by default an `ImageField` will not display the image.

`models.ImageField` uses a `forms.ImageField` to render the field in a form by default, which inherits its default widget from `forms.FileField`. As you've discovered, that `ClearableFileInput` form widget does not display the image.

[One fairly simply way](https://gist.github.com/anhtran/f6d91a41da2bd5bbfc17868b7f528a88?permalink_comment_id=3775690#gistcomment-3775690) to achieve what you want is to create a new `ClearableFileInput` widget subclass that renders a customized template. The customized template can then include an `<img>` tag to display it:

```py
class ImageWidget(forms.widgets.ClearableFileInput):
    template_name = "catalog/widgets/image_widget.html"
```

And the template, in this case derived from the `clearable_file_input.html` template that Django uses for `ClearableFileInput` widgets:

```
{% if widget.is_initial %}
    <p>
        <img src="{{ widget.value.url }}">
        {% if not widget.required %}
            <input type="checkbox" name="{{ widget.checkbox_name }}" id="{{ widget.checkbox_id }}"{% if widget.attrs.disabled %} disabled{% endif %}>
            <label for="{{ widget.checkbox_id }}">{{ widget.clear_checkbox_label }}</label>
        {% endif %}<br>
    </p>
{% endif %}
<input type="{{ widget.type }}" name="{{ widget.name }}"{% include "django/forms/widgets/attrs.html" %}>
```